# VBA Outlook ribbon customisation - Button name and icon changes to reflect sensitivity state

Tags: xml, vba, email, outlook, ribbon

Company has asked for a custom ribbon button in outlook to set email sensitivity as 'private'.

Created a new button in outlook ribbon with Outlook option, then assigned the macro below. However Boss wants a button that changes name and Icon to reflect the current privacy state, rather than a MsgBox output.

I've read that I need to make changes with XML but not sure how to implement this with my VBA below. Am I approaching this the right way?

Here is pic of custom button I made. [Button Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TN31.png)

Vba module

```
Sub TogglePrivateSensitivity()
If ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.Sensitivity = Outlook.OlSensitivity.olPrivate   Then
ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.Sensitivity = Outlook.OlSensitivity.olNormal

MsgBox ("This email is now public")
Else
ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.Sensitivity = Outlook.OlSensitivity.olPrivate
MsgBox ("This email is now private")
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ribbon XML must specify callbacks (and implement them of course) that return the button caption and the image instead of hardcoding the values. You can force a refresh of your control by calling IRibbonUI.Invalidate. IRibbonUI can be retrieved from the OnLoad callback of your ribbon.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. I've found the XML file and had a look through it. Please forgive me I'm pretty new with VBA and XML, do you know of some examples I can follow with using callbacks to the xml?

Comment: I have never done that in VBA, but I think the idea is the same - for a button, instead of specifying the label attribute, specify getLabel attribute and provide the name of the callback that will return the string. To foce Outlook refresh the button caption, call IRibbonUI.Invalidate.